# WH_CBT hook another thread works in XP but Win7

Tags: c++, hook, intercept

I want to implement a hook example for intercept message from my WinForm application to another process such as 'notepad' . (not a global hook , just thread hook for monitor specified thread , HookType is WH_GETMESSAGE)

i wrote a hook dll by c++ and use it in c# .

After that ,i opened notepad from start menu or type cmd -> notepad . i found that i can get message from notepad just in xp environment , threr are no message sent in win 7.

Then , i tried to create 'notepad' process by my WinForm application ( put a button on my form and use Process.Start("Notepad.exe") for open it ), Mysteriously, it works in win 7 .

So , i don't know why it doesn't work when the notepad start from start menu in win 7 .

In xp , , i can get message whether notepad start from start menu or by my application

Comment: Is notepad running as administrator? (Just a random thought)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved this myself .
just generate c++ dll whit right platform .. win7 base on x64  , then , everything goes ok . :)